# Why can't I import ListedColorMap from matplotlib.colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am using the Anaconda distribution of python 2.7 and specifically the iPython shell (not sure if shell is the right term here).

When I try to do `from matplotlib.colors import ListedColorMap` I get back this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-6f067472330e> in <module>()
----> 1 from matplotlib.colors import ListedColorMap    
ImportError: cannot import name ListedColorMap
```

However, when I do `from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm` it does work and I don't get any exception.

What might be the cause of this issue and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write as ["ListedColormap"](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html):
`from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap`

"M" must be in lowercase - you made a misprint

Comment: So I guess we can close as "simple typographical error"?!

Comment: Yep, close this thread

Comment: o.0 what a goofy mistake by me